# Reading/Writing to JSON adds an extra unnecessary curly bracket }

Tags: python, json, io

I am writing a program in Python where a JSON local file needs to be updated with the last processed item in a database so that the process kicks off again from that point. 
Problem I am having in my code is that sometimes, it adds an extra curly bracket "}" to the end of the code causing the JSON to become invalid. This then breaks the scheduled process until the JSON file is updated.

I know that I can first read the file to the object, then close the file then open it again to write to it but personally it doesn't feel like the code would be as clean given that it is being constantly written to so that the tracking of the last processed item is not lost.

```py
import json


with open(_SETTINGS, 'r+') as settings:
    _last_processed = log['@timestamp']
    settings_data[env]['last_processed'] = _last_processed
    settings.seek(0)
    # settings.truncate()
    json.dumps(settings_data, settings, indent=2)
```

The JSON file, _SETTINGS, looks like as follows:

```
{
  "UAT": {
    "last_processed": "2019-10-10T00:00:00.0000Z"
  },
  "DEV": {
    "last_processed": "2019-10-10T00:00:00.0000Z"
  }
}
```

Annoyingly what only sometimes gets returned is the above JSON but with an extra closing curly bracket "}" as below.

```
{
  "UAT": {
    "last_processed": "2019-10-10T00:00:00.0000Z"
  },
  "DEV": {
    "last_processed": "2019-10-10T00:00:00.0000Z"
  }
}}
```

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: Use mode `w` instead of `r+`, the bracket might be a left-over from an earlier version of the file that was 1 byte longer.

Comment: Can't do that because I first read the file to get the last processed item then write to the same file. I know I can separate the step into two steps by doing a 'r' then close file followed by the 'w' to write to it but I want to do it as a single block of code. If there is no way besides that then I will have to go with that.

Comment: That would be better. Or at least call `.truncate()` on the file.

Comment: Would the truncate not remove all entries? I need to keep the other entries to track for UAT and PROD. I think I will separate the function. Kinda annoying...